# ALOS files contain DEM, MSK, STK files

Tags: dem

### Can anyone explain to me (in simple terms) under what circumstances one might use the MSK and STK files in my DEM downloads from ALOS?
I have used the DEM files but am concerned I might be missing out on other important terrain information/data.

I have since got an answer from the technical team from ALOS, which doesn't particularly help. But maybe there are experts here who can decipher for me please?

> First, the MSK file has information that indicates invalid or valid
> values for the DSM file. Furthermore, if it is a valid value, it is
> possible to know the DSM information used for each valid value number
> from the mask information.
>
> Next, the STK file shows the number of ALOS / PRISM observation scenes
> used to create the AW3D30 DSM. The accuracy of the height information
> of AW3D30 tends to improve as the number of observation scenes
> increases. To find out which pixels of the valid values in the DSM
> file are using the AW3D30, you can check the MSK file described
> earlier.

Answer (score -3):

https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/aw3d30v3.2_product_e_e1.0.pdf

Please check the latest documentation for the details.

Comment: I have read the document before, hence my reason for asking the question. Can you give me a tangible reason or 2 as to what I would use the mask files for? I honestly do not understand what that document is telling me and hence why I might use the files.